# Bundling SQL Scripts and other file-based resources in SSIS project deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a way you can add SQL scripts, or flat files in general, into SSIS projects such that they get bundled into the same `ispac` file with the `dtsx` packages?

Example use case: pulling the SQL code from an "execute SQL" task into a separate file where it can work with source control diffs more easily for peer reviews, etc.

It looks like miscellaneous files in the same project directory do NOT get bundled into the `ispac`, even when Visual Studio recognizes them as miscellaneous files in the project.

Comment: What's the use case? Even if you can bundle it, how you would tell the installer to access and execute it?

Comment: updated to explain my use case.  Since the ispac is an archive format it seems like it should be reasonable to reference other resources within the ispac by path within the archive, analogous to embedded resources in an assembly or the equivalent in Java

Comment: Ok. I found that you can't do this (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

### Nope. You Can't.

**Source : MSDN - [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290(v=sql.130).aspx)**

> The project deployment file does not capture all of the information
>   contained in the Integration Services project file (.dtproj
>   extension). For example, additional text files that you use for
>   writing notes are not stored in the project deployment file and thus
>   are not deployed to the catalog.

Since SQL scripts would also be text files with .SQL extension, it looks like they won't be included in the `.ispac` archive deployment file, even if you place them in the **"Miscellaneous"** folder inside your SSIS Project

**Here's a screenshot of the relevant text from MSDN**

[image: ssis ispac include miscellaneous files and sql scripts]